# Constructing a Certain Bijection for Irrational Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can one construct a bijection $f$ from set of real numbers to set of all irrational numbers?

Comment: How have you concluded that $f(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ if we don't yet know what $f$ is?

Comment: clearly $f$ is injective...

Comment: You should put all these details in the question. We can't help you if we don't have all the information.

Comment: The definition of $f$ is not clear. Does it apply to any $x$? Or does it apply only to $x$ having the form $a +b\sqrt 2$? In that case, how do determine $a, b$? For example, if $x = \sqrt 2$, then $a = \sqrt 2, b = 0$ and $a =0, b =1$ are possible solutions. I therefore voted to close your question.

Comment: Correct... I have fixed it

Comment: @WiWo, you have edited your good question into a bad one! Please consider re-instating the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\xi$ be your favourite positive irrational number. We will construct an explicit bijection $g:\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q\to \Bbb R$; then your $f$ is just the inverse of $g$.

Let $(q_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be an enumeration of the rationals.

Every irrational number not of the form $n\xi$ for some integer $n\ge 1$ gets mapped to itself.

Otherwise, if $x$ is of the form $2n\xi$, then $g(x)=n\xi$; and if $x$ is of the form $(2n+1)\xi$, then $g(x)=q_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I find your construction much better, I wanted to ask if its possible to review my construction of $f$ and if its possible to use it in your method

Comment: @WiWo: Your construction is ill-defined. What if $x$ is _not_ equal to $a+b\sqrt 2$?

Comment: I agree! If I made second type of $f(x)$ be $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is otherwise not equal to $a+b\sqrt{2}$, then it would work.

Comment: @WiWo: Please edit your question accordingly. I think our constructions are very similar; in particular, your $f$ looks good to me.